# How to prevent a record from being affected by the ORDER BY RAND() function?

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin, mysqli

I am building an online exam site using php and mysql. It's just for MCQ type questions.
Here is my database structure:
1) QUESTIONS ( Exam_ID, Questions_ID, Questions_Des)

2) OPTIONS ( Question_ID, Option, Options_ID, Atype)

1) TRACK (User_ID, Exam_ID, Question_ID)

The table TRACK keeps a record of which questions have been answered already by which students.

The field Atype in the OPTIONS table indicates if the answer option is STATIC or null.

I want the questions randomized for each student without repetition and I achieved that with:

```
"SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question_ID NOT IN (SELECT question_ID FROM track where User_ID = '<user_id>') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"
```

This works perfectly.

And I also randomize the various answer options so that no two students have the same answer pattern for a question. The code i used is:

```
SELECT * FROM options WHERE question_ID = '<question_ID>' ORDER BY RAND()
```

A problem arises when a question is of this form:
Question: which of the following are even numbers?
A) 1
B) 3
C) 7
D) None of the above.

When this randomizes, option D could now be option A which makes no sense since there aren't any answers above it. That is why I added another field to the options table known as Atype which indicates if the answer is static or not.

How can I then query the options such that any answer option which is not STATIC won't be affected by the ORDER BY RAND() function so that when it randomizes option A, B and C will randomize but not Option D which has been marked as static. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Why does it have to be one query?  You're retrieving two sets of [similar-looking] data that you want to process [slightly] differently. Why not pull them in two queries It's not as if you're working with hugely volatile data that might change in between the two.

Comment: Thanks @Phill W. Please could you show me a sample query of what you mean

Comment: Your application executes two queries: 
[1]: select * from questions where type = 'STATIC'; 
[2] select * from questions where type <> 'STATIC' order by RAND();  
You do realise that you might not get the first list in order, don't you?  Rows in Relational Tables have no intrinsic order.  You must use "order by" clauses to get them in the right order consistently.

Comment: Thanks @Phill W. Let me edit the post so the question is clearer.

Comment: [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/236973/distribute-n-questions-to-m-students-with-all-students-having-the-same-questions/236981#236981) - my answer - might be of help. Also, I started work on your issue [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/czb2WEMjJjfq5UTvkJRGQD/15) - just don't have time at the minute - gotta put bread on the table ;-) If it hasn't been answered by the weekend, I may get a chance to have a look - +1 for an interesting variation!

Comment: Also, you could look [here](http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm) - search for "exam".

Comment: Please don't cross-post.

Comment: I finally succeeded in getting the results i wanted. It's actually quite simple. Here is the query i used. SELECT * FROM options ORDER BY atype='STATIC',RAND().   And it works like magic.